# There is no topology on the space of random variables s.t. a.s. convergent seqs are the converging seqs?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, topologies

The post [*When do we find convergence in distribution to independent variables?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588401/when-do-we-find-convergence-in-distribution-to-independent-variables) prompted me to review [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution). As I read on, I encountered a property about almost sure convergence that I do not understand.

> The concept of almost sure convergence does not come from a topology on the space of random variables. This means there is no topology on the space of random variables such that the almost surely convergent sequences are exactly the converging sequences with respect to that topology. In particular, there is no metric of almost sure convergence.

I would appreciate someone unpacking what this result is about and why it is true.

Comment: You might have better luck on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: And [How to understand "a.s. convergence does not come from a metric, or even from a topology"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074542/how-to-understand-a-s-convergence-does-not-come-from-a-metric-or-even-from-a).